# How to get ListItem position when pressed on ImageButton element in ListView

Tags: android

I have a custom list view ...

each item of a List view I am constructing with the layout...

My layout will have 4 text views and one ImageButton.. My listview size is 10 elements.

Now I need launch different activity depending on the position of the button pressed..

Like if user pressed third list item ImageButton then I need to display 3 rd activity..

Issue I am facing is I am unable to get the position number of the ImageButton..

I have added "setOnItemClickLIstener()" but its not getting called when imagebutton is pressed..

Please help me how to get the position of pressed ImageButton...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it, one is putting the listener on the button and then on your adapter you should put a listener on every button and on these listeners you already put the right activity to call.

Or you could NOT put the listener on the button and use setOnItemClickListener on the list, then you will have your position and can start the right activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your getview()  method of you adapter... put this method...

```
  mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 private int pos = position;

  @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "position="+ String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
 });
```

this will toast the position... (or you can get the value of position)

Answer (score 0):

I solve in this way.
In my getview() method of my adapter i've set the tag to my ImageButton and save it in the 
setOnClickListener method for use later. holder is a static class used inside the getView() method.

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){ 
     //...
     holder.imgButton = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBookProject);
     holder.imgButton.setTag(position);
     holder.imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
        String tag = v.getTag().toString();
        Log.d("clicked button", tag);
        //store the position of the clicked button for later use in the code
        lastClicked = Integer.parseInt(tag);
        //perform my action
        }

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your XML file:

```
<ListView  
....
....
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```